# How to control height of ComboBox Editor within a JTable with large row height?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox

I have a JTable in which I want ComboBox editor in one column and a TextArea in another column.

When the entered TextArea includes multiple text lines I'm resizing the row height successfully, however when selecting the cell with the ComboBox Editor (in the same row) the ComboBox drop down looks a little "vertically stretched" i.e. it fills the whole row height.

[image]

Is this just how it is, or is there some way of setting the maximum or preferred height of the drop down marker of the ComboBox, so this is the same in all rows regardless of row height?

This is demonstrated in the following (with thanks to [Dr Heinz at JavaSpecialists](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue106.html))

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;

public class ComboAndTextAreaTest extends JFrame {
    private final JTable table = new JTable(10, 2);

    public ComboAndTextAreaTest() {
        super(System.getProperty("java.vm.version"));

        Vector boxVals = new Vector();
        boxVals.add("First");
        boxVals.add("Second");
        boxVals.add("Third");
        final JComboBox box = new JComboBox(boxVals);

        box.setSelectedIndex(0);

        final TableCellEditor boxEditor = new DefaultCellEditor(box);          

        box.setPreferredSize(new Dimension());
        TableColumnModel cmodel = table.getColumnModel();
        // First column is ComboBox based
        cmodel.getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(new DefaultTableCellRenderer());
        cmodel.getColumn(0).setCellEditor(boxEditor);
        // Second column is Text Area
        cmodel.getColumn(1).setCellRenderer(new TextAreaRenderer());
        cmodel.getColumn(1).setCellEditor(new TextAreaEditor());

        // The following doesn't appear to have any effect
        int cw = cmodel.getColumn(0).getPreferredWidth();
        Dimension pd = new Dimension(cw, 18);
        box.setMaximumSize(pd);

        String test = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";

        for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
            table.setValueAt(boxVals.get(row % 3), row, 0);
            table.setValueAt(test, row, 1);
        }
        test = test + "\n" + test + test + test + "\n" + test + test;
        table.setValueAt(test, 4, 1);

        getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(table));
        setSize(600, 600);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ComboAndTextAreaTest();
    }
}
```

EDIT: For clarity (following comments about Renderers) the following is slightly amended example removing bespoke TextArea handling.  The question applies in this case as well.

[image: JComboBox Editor in JTable]

And the following code:

```
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;

public class ComboAndTextAreaTest extends JFrame {
    private final JTable table = new JTable(10, 2);

    public ComboAndTextAreaTest() {
        super(System.getProperty("java.vm.version"));

        Vector boxVals = new Vector();
        boxVals.add("First");
        boxVals.add("Second");
        boxVals.add("Third");
        final JComboBox box = new JComboBox(boxVals);

        box.setSelectedIndex(0);

        final TableCellEditor boxEditor = new DefaultCellEditor(box);          

        TableColumnModel cmodel = table.getColumnModel();
        // First column is ComboBox based
        cmodel.getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(new DefaultTableCellRenderer());
        cmodel.getColumn(0).setCellEditor(boxEditor);
        cmodel.getColumn(0).setMaxWidth(100);
        // Second column is just text field
        cmodel.getColumn(1).setCellRenderer(new DefaultTableCellRenderer());
        cmodel.getColumn(1).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(new JTextField()));
        cmodel.getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(200);

        String test = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";

        for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++) {
            table.setValueAt(boxVals.get(row % boxVals.size()), row, 0);
            table.setValueAt(test, row, 1);
        }

        // special processing on row 4 to show row height and affect on combobox
        String test2 = "This row set with greater height - combo drop down in prev cell affected during edit";

        table.setValueAt(test2, 4, 1);
        table.setRowHeight(4, 50);
        getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(table));
        setSize(600, 600);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ComboAndTextAreaTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: edit class TextAreaRenderer and to provide required changes

Comment: @mKorbel hi, I'm a little confused - the Renderer for the ComboBox column is purely default Renderer and the ComboBox only shows in Editor mode (as image when row selected) within DefaultCellEditor - I presume you mean create a "ComboBoxEditor"?

Comment: not image posted and description talking about Rendering issue, search for good renderer, where is JTextArea placed into JScrollPane and restricted max size (PreferredSize),  (JTextArea and JScrollPane) should be declared as local variables in renderer to avoids recreating a JComponents on runtime

Comment: @mKorbel - I didn't think I mentioned Rendering - my feeling is this is more about Editors - as the combo drop down is only visible (as per the image) in Editor mode, when cell is selected.  JTextArea is placed in Renderer within TextAreaRenderer (as per the "JavaSpecialists" link above code) - I can post the two classes code directly if you wish (was just trying to reduce clutter).

Comment: please did you research for good renderer, then give up

Comment: an editor is always sized to the size of the cell, (nearly, except extremely dirty tricks :-) nothing you can do about that. A workaround might be a custom editor, f.i. a panel containing the combo. A bit of work involved, though.

Comment: @kleopatra thanks, that's useful to know - I half suspected it but wasn't sure if there was something I was missing.  I had a quick go at the panel/combo approach you flagged and got close, but a) not sure it looks better and b) not a priority for me right now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@kleopatra (in comments on question) in response to question "Is this just how it is?" has basically answered this as "...[yes] an editor is always sized to the size of the cell, (nearly, except extremely dirty tricks :-) nothing you can do about that. A workaround might be a custom editor, f.i. a panel containing the combo. A bit of work involved, though".